# how to add information from difrent table?

Tags: codeigniter, join

i am new in CI i have a data the result from a process and i want to additional information on that from difretnt table like this picture[image]. 
both table are linked to an id (idhn). i make query join in model like this

```
function gabung(){
         $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('metode'); 
        $this->db->join('hasil_inden','hasil_inden.idhn=metode.idhn');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
   }
```

i called $metode in controller like this

```
 ' $metode = $this->Proses_model->gabung();'
```

but it is not work  undefined variablev $metode  please give me solution to fix it

Comment: change `return $query -> result();` to `print_r( $query -> result() );`, what output do you get?

Comment: i get contest of the table $metode that want to show

Comment: where did you get the `undefined variable $metode` message? and how do you pass the `$metode` variable to the view?

Comment: The error is not in the code you show. It is in the view file. Show that code.

Comment: write it without single quotes in your controller  
$metode = $this->Proses_model->gabung();

Comment: i think you forgot to pass variable $metode  to view show your full controller function code

Comment: this code to show $metode in view

  <?= $metode->metode_pembelajaran ;?>